# C# - Class can't use Enity Framework Column?

Tags: c#

i have a failure in my code, eg a NullReferenceException:
I have two important classes: One in which i implemented my Interface-Methods and the program-class which includes the main-method.

The Like-Method in the Interfaceclass:

```
        public void Like(List<User> eingeloggt, Mensch geliked)
    {
        User user_eingeloggt = eingeloggt[0];
        DBContext Datenbank = new DBContext();
        User utest = Datenbank.DBUser.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals(user_eingeloggt.Benutzername));
        Mensch dbliker = Datenbank.DBMenschen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals(utest.Benutzername));
        Mensch dbgeliked = Datenbank.DBMenschen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals(geliked.Benutzername));

        List<Mensch> return_likes_dbliker = new List<Mensch>();
        List<Mensch> return_likes_dbgeliked = new List<Mensch>();
        List<Mensch> return_fs_dbliker = new List<Mensch>();
        List<Mensch> return_fs_dbgeliked = new List<Mensch>();


        //LIKER - LIKES
        foreach (Like l in Datenbank.DBLikes.ToList())
        {
            if (l.Mensch1.Benutzername.Equals(dbliker.Benutzername))
            {
                return_likes_dbliker.Add(l.Mensch2);
            }
            if (l.Mensch2.Benutzername.Equals(dbliker.Benutzername)) // <- NULL-REFERENCE-EXCEPTION!!!!
            {
                return_likes_dbliker.Add(l.Mensch1);
            }
        }
        //GELIKED - LIKES
        foreach (Like l in Datenbank.DBLikes.ToList())
        {
            if (l.Mensch1.Benutzername.Equals(dbgeliked.Benutzername))
            {
                return_likes_dbgeliked.Add(l.Mensch2);
            }
            if (l.Mensch2.Benutzername.Equals(dbgeliked.Benutzername))
            {
                return_likes_dbgeliked.Add(l.Mensch1);
            }
        }
        //LIKER - FREUNDSCHAFTEN
        foreach (Freundschaft f in Datenbank.DBFreundschaften.ToList())
        {
            if (f.Mensch1.Benutzername.Equals(dbliker.Benutzername))
            {
                return_fs_dbliker.Add(f.Mensch2);
            }
            if (f.Mensch2.Benutzername.Equals(dbliker.Benutzername))
            {
                return_fs_dbliker.Add(f.Mensch1);
            }
        }
        //GELIKED - FREUNDSCHAFTEN
        foreach (Freundschaft f in Datenbank.DBFreundschaften.ToList())
        {
            if (f.Mensch1.Benutzername.Equals(dbgeliked.Benutzername))
            {
                return_fs_dbgeliked.Add(f.Mensch2);
            }
            if (f.Mensch2.Benutzername.Equals(dbgeliked.Benutzername))
            {
                return_fs_dbgeliked.Add(f.Mensch1);
            }
        }


        if (!return_likes_dbliker.Contains(dbgeliked) && utest.Credits < 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Du hast nicht genügend Credits, um " + dbgeliked.Benutzername + " zu liken!");
        }
        if (return_likes_dbliker.Contains(dbgeliked))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Du hast " + dbgeliked.Benutzername + " bereits geliked!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!return_likes_dbliker.Contains(dbgeliked) && utest.Credits > 10)
            {
                dbgeliked.LikeCounter++;
                utest.Credits = utest.Credits - 10;
                Like like_neu = new Like();
                like_neu.Mensch1 = dbliker;
                like_neu.Mensch2 = dbgeliked;
                Datenbank.DBLikes.Add(like_neu);
                Datenbank.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Du hast " + dbgeliked.Benutzername + " geliked! ; Verbleibende Credits: " + utest.Credits);
            }
        }
        if (return_fs_dbliker.Contains(dbgeliked) && return_fs_dbgeliked.Contains(dbliker))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Du bist mit " + dbgeliked.Benutzername + " bereits befreundet!");
        }
        else
        {
            if (return_likes_dbliker.Contains(dbgeliked) && return_likes_dbgeliked.Contains(dbliker))
            {
                Freundschaft freundschaft_neu = new Freundschaft();
                freundschaft_neu.Mensch1 = dbliker;
                freundschaft_neu.Mensch2 = dbgeliked;
                Datenbank.DBFreundschaften.Add(freundschaft_neu);
                Datenbank.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Du bist mit " + dbgeliked.Benutzername + " jetzt befreundet!");
            }
        }

    }
```

The Program-Class ( Main-Method ) :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DBContext dbc = new DBContext();
        Blind_Date_Verwaltung bdv = new Blind_Date_Verwaltung();
        List<User> user_eingeloggt = new List<User>();
        List<string> interessen = new List<string>();
        List<string> abneigungen = new List<string>();

        bdv.Registrieren("Test1-Vor", "Test1-Nach", "anscash", "anscash@web.de", "EMPIRE", "EMPIRE", "as_usal");
        bdv.Registrieren("Test1-Vor", "Test1-Nach", "anscash2", "anscash2@web.de", "EMPIRE", "EMPIRE", "as_usal");
        bdv.Registrieren("Test1-Vor", "Test1-Nach", "anscash3", "anscash3@web.de", "EMPIRE", "EMPIRE", "as_usal");
        bdv.Registrieren("Test1-Vor", "Test1-Nach", "anscash4", "anscash4@web.de", "EMPIRE", "EMPIRE", "as_usal");
        bdv.Registrieren("Test1-Vor", "Test1-Nach", "anscash5", "anscash5@web.de", "EMPIRE", "EMPIRE", "as_usal");


        bdv.Login(user_eingeloggt, "anscash", "EMPIRE");
        //bdv.Login(user_eingeloggt, "anscash2", "EMPIRE");
        //bdv.Login(user_eingeloggt, "anscash3", "EMPIRE");
        //bdv.Login(user_eingeloggt, "anscash4", "EMPIRE");
        //bdv.Login(user_eingeloggt, "anscash5", "EMPIRE");


        bdv.ProfilErzeugen(user_eingeloggt, "Rot", "186", "28.07.1994", "Homo", "Beziehung", "Ausgezogen!", 
            "Student", "Hello World", false, false, false, interessen, abneigungen);


        Mensch test_mensch1 = dbc.DBMenschen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals("anscash"));
        Mensch test_mensch2 = dbc.DBMenschen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals("anscash2"));
        Mensch test_mensch3 = dbc.DBMenschen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals("anscash3"));
        Mensch test_mensch4 = dbc.DBMenschen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals("anscash4"));
        Mensch test_mensch5 = dbc.DBMenschen.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Benutzername.Equals("anscash5"));

        bdv.Like(user_eingeloggt, test_mensch3);
```

}
My DB-Context-Class is:

```
    public class DBContext : DbContext
{

    public DBContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(null);
    }
    public DbSet<User> DBUser { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mensch> DBMenschen { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Freundschaft> DBFreundschaften { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Like> DBLikes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Admin> DBAdmin { get; set; }

}
```

}

I can use the Like-Method for one time, at the secont time, visual studio throws the Null-Reference-Exception with a "Null"-InnerException

When i insert this into the "interface"-class:
MessageBox.Show("ZZZ: " + alle_Likes[0].Mensch2.Benutzername);
The Message is : "ZZZ: "

When i insert it into the PROGRAM (Main)-Class it gives me:
"ZZZ: ancash('whatever the "Benutzername" is')"

It seems that the "Interface"-Class cannot use the EnityFramework-Column but the Program-Main-Class can do.

I know i didnt post EVERY class, although it would be helpful, i dont think there is someone who would read EVERYTHING. If thereÄs somebody out there, answer me and i will post everything.
Kind Regards
Can you help me?